# MediaPlayer using services

Tags: android

Can someone enlighten me about the android services? I'm really having a hard time understanding it. I wanted to make a music player application. Just a simple application that shows a listview of songs and has the usual buttons and functionalities of a music player. However, in creating this app, I'm thinking of what kind of service to use.  I'm thinking of using bound services but I'm confused if my decision is correct. I've read about the services but unfortunately, I could not understand it properly. I mean I know what it does but when it comes to implementing the codes, that's the time when my confusion starts. Then there's a time I read an information about implementing it as a foreground service rather than a background. Now that adds up my confusion. What will i really use? Which is which? please help me and if possible, let me understand about implementing the codes.

Comment: It depends on your app. Apps that usually use a `Service` does it in order to play an audio media even if the user has left the app. If you wish to offer the user the ability to do so, than it is possible to implment a `Service` dedicated to playing background audio media. If it is not the case, than embed a `MediaPlayer` in you `Activity` and control it using the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: I know i really should use `Service` but i don't know which of the two should be used, started or bound?

Comment: If've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the difference between a `Service` started with `startService` and one started with `bindService`is how you are going to manage its *lifecycle*.

Because you have to call `unbindService` after having called `startService`, the lifecycle of your service is intimately bound to the lifecycle of your bound component (often, an activity). As such, when you'll call unbindService, your service will be destroyed if it has no other `ServiceConnection` bound to it.

The question here is about knowing whether you would like to have your service being dependant on the lifecycle of your activity, or not. If you want to keep it around even if the user leaves your app, than use `startService` and implement the associated `onStartCommand` callback in the service.

**EDIT :** A good example of this can be found in the samples provided with the Android SDK. Take a look at the `RandomMusicPlayer`, it implements a `MusicService` that might be what you want for your app, from what I've understood.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me an example of an application that uses bound services?

Comment: Yeah, if you reload the answer, you'll see that i've posted an example as an edit.